# Is it a bad pattern to chaining epics in redux-observable?

Tags: redux-observable

The epic chain starts with a user initiated action. Then the following happens:

- user data is sent to the server, and server sends back d2 = compute(user data) (epic 1 ->
- the returned data is being sent to a different server, which returns the client a new kind of data (epic 2 ->
- this new data is needed to be able to listen to whether this data was accepted. (epic 3, end)

I chose this process because on every epic, i want to update the store to notify the user of the status of the request, which could take several seconds to complete. My preferred way was to use websockets, so the server could send status update, but I can't support that at the moment.

So the question, is it a bad pattern?

[image]